# Magento 2: How to Override a third-party module by my theme?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

I know how to override a native Magento 2 module templates such as "**magento/module-customer**", "**magento/module-contact**" etc....

But I curious to know, how to override a third party module placed in `app/code/Sample_vendor1/Sample_module1` through my theme `app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme`

Thank You.

Comment: It will be `app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Magento_Checkout/templates` or `app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Magento_Checkout/layout`

Comment: Thanks Ankit, Yes I agree "Magento_Checkout" is a magneto native module and we can override like this app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Magento_Checkout/temp‌​lates

But how override a third party module  "app/code/Sample_vendor1/Sample_module1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is done in the same way as you would override a core module's template.

```
vendor/My_vendor/My_theme/SampleVendor1_SampleModule1/templates
```

If your theme is in app/design, the path would be:

```
app/design/My_vendor/My_theme/SampleVendor1_SampleModule1/templates
```

Comment: how to override/extend other php file of a module?

Comment: What about adminhtml files in M2? For instance I am trying to extend Gene_Bluefoot and I have placed my files at `app/design/adminhtml/My_Vendor/My_Theme/Gene_Bluefoot/templates` but they are not working.

Answer (score 2):

you can override module files in theme like below

```
app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Sample_vendor1/templates
app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Sample_vendor1/layout
app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Sample_vendor1/web
```

Comment: Thanks FME, you mean 
`app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Sample_vendor1/Sample_module1/templates`
`app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Sample_vendor1/Sample_module1/layout`
`app/design/frontend/My_vendor/My_theme/Sample_vendor1/Sample_module1/web`

module name "Sample_module1" missed

Comment: i mean `app/code/namesapce/modulename ` in theme calling `namesapce_modulename/templates`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below-mentioned instructions for overriding a third party module

From :-

```
vendor/vendor_name/theme_name/vendor_module/templates

vendor/vendor_name/theme_name/vendor_module/layout

vendor/vendor_name/theme_name/vendor_module/web
```

To :-

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/vendor_module/templates

app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/vendor_module/layout

app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/vendor_module/web
```